# Blocking youtube on Ubuntu using etc/hosts

Tags: hosts

I want to block Youtube using the hosts file. I managed to do this with Facebook and Instagram but with Youtube it is not working.

Here is my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   goncalo-X541UV

#The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts

::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback  
fe00::0 ip6-localnet  
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix  
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes   
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters  

127.0.0.1 216.58.210.174  
127.0.0.1 youtube.com  
127.0.0.1 www.youtube.com  
127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com  
127.0.0.1 www.instagram.com
```

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: It doesn't block youtube. It is like I didn't do anything,but with the other websites it works.

Comment: Have you had a look at the various solutions at https://askubuntu.com/q/119547/367990 ?

Comment: So if the link @ByteCommander posted, solved your problem please accept the duplicate closure. And please dont put [solved] or [fixed] in the title.

Comment: The link didn't solve my problem. Everything just started working like it was supposed to.

Comment: thanks its worked for me, blocked youtube